# Laravel how to load specific column of related table?

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I have the following code, what I want is to take specific columns of related tables.

```
auth()->user()->load(['business', 'passwordSecurity']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select only specific columns from a relationship you should be able to do it like this:

```
auth()->user()->load([
    'business' => function ( $query ) {
        $query->select('id', 'title');
    },
    'passwordSecurity',
]);
```

Or like this:

```
auth()->user()->load(['business:id,name', 'passwordSecurity']);
```

Please note that you have to select IDs and foreign key constraints that are needed to form this relationship.

Comment: Thanks! its working, the main key was in selecting foreign key along other columns, without foreign key it returns null, my mistake was that.